# How to add Page Break dyanamically to Print page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is one long in the content on the print page, but while we print the some content of the text cut down.

[alt text http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/6766/printpage.jpg](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/6766/printpage.jpg)

please let me know , if there is any dynamic way to add page-break css. the content could be any thing.

Comment: yes , this article explain : http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

Answer (score 11):

You might also just want to prevent page breaks inside an element.

E.g. short tables that you don't want to get ripped apart when printing:

```
@media print {
    table {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

Comment: This (and the newer `break-inside`) works great when dealing with a page of dynamically generated elements.

Comment: @A.J.Bauer great solution! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As Haim Evgi referenced in this article http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

In addition to what's already described in the article, I would like to point out that it's good practice to use .page-break-before: auto instead of .page-break-before: always. The "auto" will break the page only if the contents are at the end if the page, this will prevent breaking the page and leaving a lot of blank space.

The CSS

```
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: auto; }
}
```

The HTML

```
<div>some content</div>
<div class="page-break">more content, this content may be short or long</div>
<div class="page-break">this content may page-break if content above this <div> is at the end of the page</div>
<div class="page-break">etc,..</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the css page-break-before and page-break-after elements.