# Page break in print for dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an data on print screen page. I want that split data into one page and after that another data should be print on another page. It means data should not be split. My content is dynamic. This is my problem screenshot...

Normal page

[image]

Print page

[image]

This is my demo code..

```
<div class="row extra_bottom_border">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <section class="panel">
                    <header class="panel-heading extrarextcss">
                        <?php echo $this->lang->line('requisition_data');?>
                    </header>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                      <div class="activity terques">
                        <div class="row activity-desk printcss_class">
                          <?php 
                          if(isset($farmer_ques_ans))
                          {
                          foreach ($farmer_ques_ans as $key => $value) { ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 print_css">
                              <div class="panel" style="width: 100%;">
                                  <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 7px;padding-bottom: 7px;">
                                      <div class="arrow"></div>
                                      <h4><?php echo $value['question']; ?></h4>
                                      <p><?php echo $value['answer']; ?></p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          <?php } } ?>  
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </section>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I tried this solution link also..

[How to add Page Break dyanamically to Print page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332100/how-to-add-page-break-dyanamically-to-print-page)

But its not working fine with my code..

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: I have same problem, cannot find a solution yet, my data is comming from server and I'm using a lib that will put the data in iframe to print it. So I don't have control on the content height too.;

Comment: I found this answer on this post. It worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43627804/10559888

Answer (score 0):

try this. it's work for me. Section three should be print on page 2.

```
style="page-break-after: always;"
```

We can't split a paragraph if every paragraph have same parent.

```
<header class="panel-heading extrarextcss">
    Section 1
</header>
<div class="panel-body" style="page-break-after: always;">
    <div class="activity terques">
        <div class="row activity-desk printcss_class">
            <div class="col-lg-6 print_css" >
                <div class="panel" style="width: 100%;">
                    <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 7px;padding-bottom: 7px;">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                            <h4>Section 2</h4>
                            <p>description...</p>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 <div>
     Section 3
 </div>
```

Comment: did you try this solution on localhost?

Comment: My data is not static. It is coming from loop. So how I can print data by loop. Your data is static and You mentioned your section 3 after the parent div. So give me solution with loop where dynamic content is coming. As per your solution you can fix page break after section 2 no matter how much content is in it. My blocks is not fixed and my blocks content is also not fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Please try using this code :

.Css

```
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}
@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

.Html

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this one also but my data height is dynamic. So its not working.

Comment: This is not working if you have data dynamic data with dynamic height